# Windows service doesn't start until user login

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I have a service that logs in as a specific user.  The service works great when the user logs in, but won't start until they do so.  Is there some kind of a setting I am missing?

- This is running on a Windows 7 Ultimate box.
- The user is an administrator of the box and the service is set to automatically start.
- No errors are in the application log, and the service runs like a champ once the user logs in (without having them start it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fun one, but I figured it out this morning.

The issue is that the server was a clean Windows 7 Ultimate install.  That means the power management functionality was set to default which causes the machine to power down after 30 minutes, hence the service would stop running.  Fixed the power management settings to never sleep and running like a champ.

Thanks for the input folks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have privileges to start Windows Services (the user policy)? You can try using [ntrights.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) to make sure that he does. Also, can you start the service from Services.msc when logged in another account?

I think this is a privileges problem. Either the service login information is incorrect or the user cannot start services.

Comment: Cosmin, as stated above, the service is running just fine with no issue when the user was logged in.  If it were a privileges issue I would expect that it wouldn't run even with the user logged in.